# How do I make Quartus II compile faster

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm using Altera Quartus 2 to do a custom 8 bit processor and it takes forever to compile on my laptop. I'm only using simulations and making my processor in schematic (block diagram) and VHDL. Right now it takes around 10 minutes to compile, which is a pain since I'm more on the debugging phase of the project where I have to fix up the internal timing and make lots of very little changes to see what happens.

I'm not actually putting it on a FPGA, so do I need the compiling phases of "fitter" and "assembler"?

Can I change the contents of a memory file of one lpm_ram_dq and test it in simulation without recompiling?

In summary anyone knows how to make it compile faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of decreasing important.

- More memory.  4 GB for a 32-bit OS. 
  Some designs need more that that and
  require a 64-bit OS.
- Don't overconstrain the design.
- Change the     compilation options to not try as
  hard.  That's under assignments>
  settings> Fitter Settings>Fast Fit
  (or Auto Fit)
- 8.1 supports multiple cores.
- Hiearchical compiles help, especially if you have multiple instances of the same block.

2 minutes is really short, I agree with the previous poster.  A single gate will that take long.

Comment: 1: My laptop have 2GB memory, it should be enough for my project
2: What you mean?
3: That didn't work, it still takes a lot of time in the Fitter
4: How do I do that? I can't make it use 100% of my CPU
5: I do have lots of instances of the same block, how do I do a hiearchical compilation?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. the second observation did work. It halved the Fitter time, it went down from 8 min to 4 min. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Some useful flags to make Quartus synthesize faster if you don't care about fully optimizing your results and just want to get a pessimistic estimate or do comparisons.

```
set_global_assignment  -name PHYSICAL_SYNTHESIS_EFFORT  FAST
```

> Specifies the amount of effort, in terms of compile time, physical synthesis should use. Fast uses less compile time but may reduce the performance gain that physical synthesis is able to achieve.

```
set_global_assignment  -name FITTER_EFFORT              FAST_FIT
```

> Fast Fit decreases optimization effort to reduce compilation time, which may degrade design performance.

And instead of `execute_flow -compile`, use:

```
execute_flow -implement
```

> Option to run compilation up to route stage and skipping all time intensive algorithms after.

In a meeting with Intel/Altera engineers, using `-implement` this was ball-parked to be about 20% faster than `-compile`, and came recommended when iterating on timing-closure results.

You could also try the following:

```
set_global_assignment  -name SYNTHESIS_EFFORT           FAST
```

*Note:* This has the caveat below, although I tend to see overall faster runs in some designs.

> When set to Fast, some steps are omitted to accomplish synthesis more quickly; however, there may be some performance and resource cost. Altera recommends setting this option to Fast only when running an early timing estimate. **Running a "fast" synthesis produces a netlist that is slightly harder for the Fitter to route, thus making the overall fitting process slower**, which negates any performance increases achieved as a result of the "fast" synthesis.

**Edit (Jul 21, 2020):**

The below settings will punish your timing, but they can also help with compile time significantly, particularly on newer Stratix 10/Agilex designs:

```
set_global_assignment -name OPTIMIZATION_MODE          "AGGRESSIVE COMPILE TIME"
set_global_assignment -name ALLOW_REGISTER_RETIMING    "OFF"
set_global_assignment -name HYPER_RETIMER_FAST_FORWARD "OFF"
```

And you can also turn off timing analysis with the below:

```
set_global_assignment -name TIMEQUEST_MULTICORNER_ANALYSIS "OFF"
```

**Edit 2 (March 9, 2022):**

This setting is even faster than `AGGRESSIVE COMPILE TIME`:

```
set_blocal_assignment -name OPTIMIZATION_MODE          "FAST FUNCTIONAL TEST"
```

> This mode produces a .sof bitstream file that you can use for on-board functional testing with minimal compile time. This mode further reduces compile time beyond Aggressive Compile Time mode by limiting timing optimizations to only those for hold requirements.

Comment: I think you get the "gravedigger" badge for things like this. This question is 9 years old! But the QA was talking about doing timing optimizations. You cannot make these optimizations if you change the synthesis effort settings. Implementation will differ from the full blown compilation.

Comment: That's true in the sense that you won't be truly optimizing your compiled design and seeing real-life results, but when you're iterating on timing closure modifications and you want to see your progress you can still use these flags to do apples-to-apples comparisons to see if your updates improve Fmax.

Comment: Where do you change these settings?

Comment: @bdbasinger In the QSF file

Answer (score 2):

Some things:

- If you're not putting it on an FPGA, why compile with Quartus ? Just simulate it with Modelsim or ActiveHDL or whatever simulator you have.
- 2 minutes is a **very** short compile time. Really :-)
- Try Quartus 8, it's much faster than 7 and older
- To check that your code synthesizes correctly and see the netlist, you indeed don't need the fitter and assembler steps

Comment: 1: Not an option, I'm doing a college assignment and the professor requires Quartus II Simulation.
2: My project is now on 10 min compile time, about 6 min is in the fitter phase.
3: I'm using Quartus 8.1
4: I didn't understand that, can you explain better? I'm a hardware designer noob...

Comment: Just do a few iterative simulations with the Altera version of ModelSim, then run the Quartus simulator once you think you've got things working.  And as mentioned, don't do the full compile if you're not targeting an FPGA, just do the analysis and synthesis portion.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to simulate in Quartus, you do not have to run a full compilation. If you press Ctrl-K only the analysis and elaboration is performed. The quartus simulator should do this for you.

OTH as mention by several others: 10 minutes a very short compilation time. For real designs it is not unusual to leave it running for at least an hour.